# How to stop a drawing in turtle and move on to another drawing in a loop?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am trying to draw 10 squares inside each other. I coded this using a loop. However, I am struggling to get rid of lines that move from one square (smaller one) to the other (bigger one). How can I introduce

```
turtle.done()
```

in a loop so that square are not connected by lines (i.e., separate squares inside each other)? The code that I use is below:

```
size = 40 

for z in range(10):
    turtle.goto(-z*size,-z*size)  
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.forward(size*(2*z-1))                                   
        turtle.left(90)
turtle.done()
```

Comment: Lift the pen between squares!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `turtle.penup()` and `turtle.pendown()` functions:

```
import turtle
size = 40 

for z in range(10):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-z*size,-z*size)  
    turtle.pendown()
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.forward(size*(2*z-1))                                   
        turtle.left(90)
```